# Opencart if product available Button show else disable that button

Tags: opencart, product

Hi i'm creating a application using Opencart. It fully customized, i have doubt in this.

1. I have **filter.tpl** page, in this page i need to display and hide button based on product availability
   Eg:
   If product available show like this
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THe8z.jpg)

   else button show like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL0wX.jpg)

Am trying this fowling code using `ajax`

**filter.tpl**

```
$('input[name=\'filter_name\']').autocomplete({
'source': function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/getProductCheck' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            response($.map(json, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item['name'],
                    value: item['product_id']
                }
            }));
        }
    });
},
'select': function(item) {
    $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').val(item['label']);
}
```

});

In controller
**product.php**

```
public function getProductCheck()
{
        /*Some code here*/
}
```

Comment: So you can use **if ($product['quantity'])** statement for example

Comment: ya you are correct Alex. And thanks for replay

Comment: nice :) Then I can post comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the out put am using `javascript` following code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div style='display:none;' id='instock'>
        <a class='instock-btn'>Product / Solution Available</a> 
            <input type='submit' class='btn-orng available' name='' value="Click here for more details" size='20' />    
    </div>
    <div style='display:none;' id="outstock">
        <input type='submit' class='outstock-btn' name='' value="Product / Solution Not Available" size='20' /> 
        <input type='submit' class='btn-orng' name='' value="We will contact you at the earliest" size='20' />  
    </div> 
</div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dia1').on('change', function() {
        //var value =
      if (this.value <='320' )
      {
        $("#instock").show();
        $("#outstock").hide();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#instock").hide();
        $("#outstock").show();
      }
    });
     $('#len1').on('change', function() {
        //var value =
      if (this.value <='310' )
      {
        $("#instock").show();
        $("#outstock").hide();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#instock").hide();
        $("#outstock").show();
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can use `if ($product['quantity'])` statement for example

Comment: in template where you can see **foreach ($products)** statement